# Join two tables using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Table details:

**Login**:

```
 Loginid    username
 -------------------
  1         a
  2         b
  3         c
  4         d
  5         e
```

**Personal**:

```
 Loginid    fname   lname
 ------------------------
  1         nitin   kumar
  2         pravin  kumar
```

I want result like this:

```
  Loginid  username  fname   lname
  --------------------------------
    1        a       nitin   kumar   
    2        b       pravin   kumar
    3        c 
    4        d
    5        e
```

but when I used join

```
var balance = (from a in dbContext.login
               join c in dbContext.Personal on a.loginid equals c.loginid
               select new { a, c }).ToList();
```

result shows only two rows

How to do it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as shown below.

```
var balance = (from a in dbContext.login
               join c in dbContext.Personal on a.loginid equals c.loginid into lg
               from x in lg.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new { a.Loginid,a.username,x.fname,x.lname
              }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join instead of join.

For example:
http://www.devcurry.com/2011/01/linq-left-join-example-in-c.html